# CocoaPods Using Private Pods - Error on #import file

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a project which is using CocoaPods as the dependancy manager. In this project we have 2 git submodules and are using pods to manage these, the Podfile looks like this;

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'WHCore', :path => 'Native SDK/WHCore'
pod 'WHUICommon', :path => 'Native SDK/WHUICommon'
```

This works great and builds fine, however when declaring the #import  it fails to find the folder.

How can I make this import work?

Comment: did you run `pods update`?

Comment: Yes I ran pod update and it installs all required dependencies.

Comment: are you sure you open the workspace and not the project file (happens to me all the time). At your iOS project I mean.

Comment: Yeah definitely on the workspace.

Comment: Note that if you changed something at `Native SDK/WHCore` or `Native SDK/WHUICommon`, those edits will persist (since you are using `:path`).

Comment: Make sure that the submodule files you are referencing exist under Pods (the project) /Pods/(you submodule name). And also note that, when importing, you have to use these brackets: '<' '>'. It should be `#import <WHCore.h>` not `#import "WHCore.h"`

Comment: Did you check that the imports are actually there (i.e. in the Pods project)?

Comment: No they don't exist in the pods project, they exist in their own project.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer;**

For reference the s.source in the spec files for each pod was incorrect.

Fixing these fixes the issue.